# Run command after docker-compose up for one image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got a docker-compose.yml that looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql2
     restart: always
     ports:
         - "3306:3306"
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wptest
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     volumes:
         - ./site/:/var/www/html/
         - ~/playground/certs/:/etc/ssl/certs/
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wptest
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

volumes:
    db_data:
```

It works and my wordpress installation is fine - except for the fact that there is a self-signed cert in the mix. So when I try to update my wordpress installation or something, it fails (same with plugins).

If I get into the bash shell of the container and run `update-ca-certificates` it finds my keys and installs them and then I can run updates without issue.

My question is - can I automate that, so it automatically pulls in my certs and runs the command after the container is up while still allowing me to use `docker-compose up` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a simple Dockerfile that pulls from the wordpress image and add a RUN command with whatever you want to do.

```
FROM wordpress:latest

RUN your-command-here
```

And then change you docker-compose to use this new image instead of the official wordpress one, probably something like:
(notice the build arguments)

```
   wordpress:
     volumes:
         - ./site/:/var/www/html/
         - ~/playground/certs/:/etc/ssl/certs/
     depends_on:
       - db
     build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wptest
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
```

Comment: Does the command run after the container is up? Just curious because I tried putting in a command like `cat /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.crt >> /var/www/html/ca-bundle.crt` and it errors saying `Directory nonexistant`